# Route given by traceroute and ping does not match routing table

Tags: networking, routing, traceroute

I have a network of over 100 hosts running CentOs 7 With Quagga installed on all of them.

Between certain hosts, the route given by traceroute (and incrementing ttl flag with ping) does not match the route given if you use the "ip route" command and follow each link to the destination host.

This doesnt happen with all hosts, just between certain ones. I cant find any pattern in hosts that have this issue.

Comment: Can you share the details of the misbehaving systems, along with the tests you have done and the disagreeing outputs?

Comment: Yes, people can't help you without the details.